# The use intention *or* The intention of use

Tags: expressions, grammaticality-in-context

I carry out a marketing survey about a new service, and I wonder what is the most appropriate expression for a title :

"**The use intention**" OR "**The intention of use**" ?

The question was "Do you intend to use this service?".

I have the same issue with this expression :

> "**The equipments purchase intention**"
>
> "**The purchase intention of equipments**"
>
> "**The equipments intention of purchase**"

I'm french, and am not that fluent in English.

Comment: Being a non-native speaker, I'm not sure either. Instinctively, I would rephrase your "real question" as "Your intention to purchase equipment". I believe you can use either *Your* or *The*, "intention" goes well with "to", and "equipment" shouldn't have "s".

Answer (score 1):

While

> "the intention of use"

is a valid way of saying

> "the reason you want to use"

it lacks flow.  A more easy to understand way of saying this would be

> "the intended use"

...meaning "you intend to use this, but what do you intend to use this for?"

As for the other phrase

> "the reason for purchase"

would (if I understand correctly) be what you want to get across.  If I intended to purchase something, I would be planning on it.  The intention is either "to purchase" or "not to purchase".

Comment: Agreed - ***intended use*** and ***reason for purchase*** are probably the most common phrasings for such contexts. The stipulation that a product should be [*fit for its intended use*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fit+for+its+intended+use%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is often exactly the wording used in legal documents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It should actually go this way:

> Your intention behind the purchase of the equipment?

The sentence you gave, provides a very different meaning, though.
Saying:

> The equipment's intention of purchase.

implies that the equipment wanted to purchase something, and I am sure that is not want you meant.

By, the way, welcome to the ELL stackexchange site!